# Android upload a long JSON string over REST

Tags: android, json, rest, post

I have a REST interface for uploading some data stored on my local Android phone to the server over a REST interface. The data is in JSON. It works fine if I have small number of records to upload. But when the number of record reaches big numbers, for example 200. And each record is about 50 characters on average, I am getting failures. I think it is due to the size of the JSON string being too big. Any suggestion how should I do in this case? My server side is a simple PHP that gets the JSON string and parse it and store it in mysql.

Comment: Have you checked which end the problem is on? I.e. Saw that the packets are comin out of the device ok?

Comment: What kind of failures are you getting? What is the response code and response message?

Comment: What method are you using to send the data? GET has a size limit (not sure what it is) but it sounds like you should be using POST since you are changing data server side (presumably).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and questions. After some debugging, it was actually due to timeout. So it is working now after I changed timeout value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions and questions. After some debugging, it was actually due to timeout. So it is working now after I changed timeout value. Just want to have an answer to this question for anyone who might have similar problem.